# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php

```
<?php
    include_once 'session.php';
    include 'database.php';
    class user{

        private $db;

        public function __construct(){
                $this->db= new Database();


        }   
        public function userRegistration($data){
                    $name         = $data['name'];
                    $email          = $data['email'];
                    $password    = md5($data['password']);
                    $chk_email = $this->emailCheck($email);





                                            if($name == "" or  $email == "" or $password == "" ){
                                                $msg = "<div class = ' alert alert-danger'><strong>Error !</strong>Field must not be empty</div>" ;   //bootstrap aleart massage 
                                                return $msg;
                                            }


                                                         if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)=== false){  // email validate
                                                                $msg = "<div class ='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error ! </strong>Email address is not valid</div>";
                                                                return $msg;

                                                        }

                                            if ($chk_email==true){

                                            $msg = "<div class ='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error ! </strong>This email is already exist</div>";
                                            return $msg;

                                    }

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO register_tbl(name,username,email,password,gender) VALUES(:name,:username,:email,:password,:gender)";
                            $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
                            $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
                            $query->bindValue(':email',$email);
                            $query->bindValue(':password',$password);           
                            $result=$query->execute();//problem is here ..
                            if($result){
                                $msg = "<div class = 'alert alert-success'><strong>Success .</strong>You have register now.</div>";
                                return $msg;

                            }else{
                                $msg = "<div class = 'alert alert-danger'><strong>Sorry !</strong>Some thing is not right</div>";
                            }


        }



                public function emailCheck($email){
                    $sql = "SELECT email FROM register_tbl WHERE email = :email ";
                    $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql ); // prepare() is the method of PDO class;
                    $query->bindValue(':email',$email);  //bindValue() is the method of PDO class;
                    $query->execute();
                    if($query->rowCount()>0){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }       
                }

                public function getLoginUser($email,$password){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM register_tbl WHERE email = :email AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
                    $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql ); // prepare() is the method of PDO class;
                    $query->bindValue(':email',$email);  //bindValue() is the method of PDO class;
                    $query->bindValue(':password',$password); 
                    $query->execute();
                    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    return $result;

                }

        public function userLogin($data){

            $email          = $data['email'];
            $password    = md5($data['password']);

                                            if( $email == "" or $password == "" ){
                                                $msg = "<div class = ' alert alert-danger'><strong>Error !</strong>Field must not be empty</div>" ;   //bootstrap aleart massage 
                                                return $msg;
                                            }
                                             if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)=== false){  // email validate
                                                $msg = "<div class ='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error ! </strong>Email address is not valid</div>";
                                                return $msg;                                        

                                            if ($chk_email==true){

                                            $msg = "<div class ='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error ! </strong>This email is not exist</div>";
                                            return $msg;

                                    }
                                $result = $this->getLoginUser($email,$password);
                                if($result){
                                     Session :: init();
                                     Session :: setinit('login',true);
                                     Session :: setinit('id',$this->id);
                                     Session :: setinit('name',$this->name);
                                     Session :: setinit('username',$this->username);
                                     Session :: setinit('loginmsg',"<div class ='alert alert-success'><strong>Success ! </strong>You are login.</div>");

                                    header('index.php');

                                }else{echo "<script class = 'alert alert-danger'><strong>Error</strong>some thing wrong</script>";}


        }

}
    }
```

?>

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/log/user.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/log/user.php(51): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/log/registration.php(9): user->userRegistration(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/log/user.php on line 51
please help me ....

Comment: Parameters count is wrong. As simple as that.

Comment: `$query->bindValue(':gender',$gender); ` + same for username. That's what the error message tells you. (EDIT: both are not defined yet)

Comment: 3 does not equal 5

Comment: and don't use md5

Answer (score 0):

You specified 5 parameters on your SQL:

```
:name,:username,:email,:password,:gender
```

But you only binded 3:

```
$query->bindValue(':name',$name);
$query->bindValue(':email',$email);
$query->bindValue(':password',$password);
```

Comment: *"You specified 4 parameters on your SQL"* - 1...2...3...4... **5**.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You commented 2 times but you only needed one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver this guy didn't know the difference between 4 and 5 *lol* or have I miscounted? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41623367/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, it was a typo...

Comment: Thank you . Thank you so much ..........